# Как взять callback data? Telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Все привет. У меня есть инлайн клавиатура созданная при помощи списка и цикла for. Если создавать клавиатуру при помощи keyoba то там есть параметр copy_text_to_callback и бот понимает на какую кнопку пользователь нажал. Теперь вопрос. Как такое реализовать на чистом телеботе? (Ставить библиотеку ради одной мини-клавиатуры не хочу)

Answer (score 0):

В месте, где нужно сделать кнопки, впишите этот код:

```
#item и test это переменные, которые вы можете сменить по желанию
markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
item = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='a', callback_data='test')
markup_inline.add(item)
client.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'x', reply_markup=markup_inline)
```

Теперь нужно сделать ответ на кнопки, и в этом нам поможет этот код:

```
@client.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):

if call.data == 'test':
    bot.send_message(call.chat.id, 'Hello')
```

Если нужна еще какая-то помощь - обращайтесь, мы всегда здесь=)